# Extract city name from SQL Server Column

Tags: sql-server, data-analysis

**Background:**

I have a column  within my SQL Server table that consists of values that look like this:

```
 Location

 AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
 AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
 AM  -  Equi A2 Amsterdam
 GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo(NUM)
 GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo(NUM)
 GRU  - log Equ SP São Paulo(NUM)
 SJC1 - DR Santa Clara(FIS)
 IAD - Terremark NAV Culpepper
 HKG1 - Equin HK Hong Kong
```

**Dilemma:**

How would I extract only the actual places such as:
Sao Paulo, Amsterdam, Culpepper, Hong Kong etc in a new column?

**Desired output:**

```
 Amsterdam
 Amsterdam
 Amsterdam
 São Paulo
 São Paulo
 São Paulo
 Santa Clara
 Culpepper
 Hong Kong
```

The problem is that I cannot just split on the last blank space, due to the countries that have two words, split by a blank space. (Hong Kong, Sao Paulo)

**What I have been working on:**

```
SELECT TRIM( '- ' FROM '    Table    ') AS TrimmedString;
```

Comment: Based on the data shown I expect its impossible to just split it as there does not appear to be a logic rule that could be followed. If you have an existing table containing country names you could see if the name exists in the string.

Comment: @DaleK I was wondering if SQL has a pattern logic such as Python  Regular Expressions (regex)

Comment: What regex pattern would find it? Given you don't know whether the city name has 1 or 2 words? If you have a regex pattern that works we *might* be able to find a way to do it in SQL, but I think its a logic issue, not a technology issue.

Comment: Perhaps with:  finding the hypen and ignoring everything that occurs before the hyphen.
Once we've found the hyphen, find a substring that contains only capital letters and/or numbers and this substring must be surrounded by 1 or more spaces

Comment: As I say, if you can provide a regex we can see if its possible in SQL. I don't think that works anyway, you have a different number of words following the hyphen, with both lower and upper case *before* the city name.

Comment: I am actively working on this. Thanks for the input

Comment: I wrote an answer having not understood the expected output correctly! It is possible and fairly simple to get all the text after the - but there is no pattern or logic as to where the province(?) becomes the city

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no extraction pattern

1. Create a table with all major city names, you can find csv’s online for this. ([example](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities))
2. Write a query that joins using like. ( notice this query is not sargable.)

Example

```
SELECT t.Locarion
, c.CityName
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN City c on t.Location LIKE '%' + c.CityName + '%'
```

3. Insert missing cities based on null values in the previous query.

Depending if this is a one time query or running it multiple times a day, you may want to change your model to have a foreign key to a cities table.